# Overridding methods in anonymous class

Tags: java

I am having two classes. Parent and Child.In the Child class I have used anonymous Inner class for overriding Parent class methods.If I add any methods in the Child's anonymous class(Parent Class) should I define the same method in the actual Parent class?.

1. Can I have my own new method definition in Anonymous Class.
2. Why the Methods in the Anonymous class should already be defined in actual Parent class

Code:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Child().CallMe();
    }       
}

class Child
{
    Parent objParent = new Parent()
    {
        void displayMsg()
        {
            System.out.println("Display Msg for Child");
        }
    };

    void CallMe()
    {
        objParent.displayMsg();
    }
}
```

So in the above example if you remove `displayMsg()` either in Parent or Child its going to display error.

Comment: This is very weird code. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: why my code displays a error msg when i remove displayMsg() in Parent or Child's anonymous Class

Comment: @JavaBeginner I think the only one that doesn't understand Java here is you, so please be polite with people trying to help you.

Comment: @JavaBeginner : Why do you think there should't be errors, when you remove `displayMsg()` in `Parent` or `Child`'s anonymous class as you say? This is quite obvious.

Comment: @Lion It may not be "obvious" to those who are new to the language. Please be gentle.

Comment: The problems with this code are pretty obvious, and can be explained. However, I'm wondering _why_ you're doing it this way? What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: Check my question above why inline class in child class displays an error

Comment: I think everybody has read your question and understand the problem with the code. What we (at least I) are trying to understand is what you're really trying to do. Why do you need the inner Parent?

Comment: @m0skit0 - I haven't meant any to hurt some one Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
Parent objParent = new Parent()
    {
        void displayMsg()
        {
            System.out.println("Display Msg for Child");
        }
    };
```

You are just overriding the `Parent` class's method `displayMsg()`. `objParent` is an inline class (which extends `Parent`) and you can have your own method in it like below (which answers 1)

```
class Child
{
    Parent objParent = new Parent()
    {
        void displayMsg()
        {
            System.out.println("Display Msg for Parent");
        }

        void someMethod() {

        }
    };

    void CallMe()
    {
        objParent.displayMsg();
    }
}
```

and you can even avoid overriding, but still define your new methods like below (which answers 2)

```
class Child
{
    Parent objParent = new Parent()
    {
        void someMethod() {

        }
    };

    void CallMe()
    {
        objParent.displayMsg();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add new method in inline class and try to access it it is not working

Comment: That is correct, Java Beginner, and why is explained both by myself and @meewoK

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Can I have my own new method definition in Anonymous Class.

**You can have new methods defined but they are only accessible by other methods of the anyonmous class.**

> 2.Why the Methods in the Anonymous class should already be defined in
>   actual Parent class

**The object your are creating is of type "Parent". Therefore it exposes only the methods provided by "Parent" objects.**

An example to understand is, if you cast any object to "Object", the new reference will only expose "Object" methods.

```
Object object = (Object)whateverObject;
```

Comment: Love the haters giving -1 for no reason :)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `displayMsg` from `Parent`, then `Child.CallMe()` will fail because `Parent` does not have defined `displayMsg`. Just implementing it in the anonymous class will not expose the method on the `Parent` class. The anonymous implementation will be a subclass. But since you assign the variable to a `Parent` type (not the actual subclass, which probably isn't possible either), it cannot resolve this method.

Adding other methods to the anonymous class is possible, but they will only be visible from within the anonymous class (unless you resolve to reflection).

Removing `displayMsg` from the anonymous class in `Child` however, shouldn´t produce an error as far as I can see. But then again, you're just instantiating a Parent...

**Edit**

I do, however, suspect that what you're looking for is simple inheritance:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    void displayMsg() {
        // Child specific displayMsg
    }
}
```

In that case, there's no need for an inner `Parent` instance in `Child`, since `Child` also is an instance of `Parent`, and inherits its behaviour.

**Edit 2**

In response to your own answer. Let's say we have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hi there, my name is " + name + ", and I'm " + age " years old";
    }
}
```

And let's say we have a class `Employee` that extends `Person`:

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    public String company;
    public double salary;

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return super.sayHello() + ". I work at " + company + " and my salary is " + salary;
    }

    public void goToWork() {
        // Go do some work!
    }
}
```

Now, consider this:

```
Person p = new Employee();
p.goToWork(); // Will not work, as the method is declared in the subclass, not in Person
```

Therefore, if I want to treat the employee as an Employee, I need to do

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.goToWork();
```

However, in both cases I can treat them as `Person`

```
Person p = new Employee();
// This works, as it's defined in Person. It will also invoke the actual sayHello
// in the Employee class
String hi = p.sayHello();
```

It would make no sense to add `goToWork` to the `Person` class, simply because you want to invoke it declared as a `Person`. Let's see what implications it would have if we did.

```
public class Student extends Person {

     private String school;

     @Override
     public String sayHello() {
         return super.sayHello() + ". I'm studying at " + school;
     }

     public void goToSchool() {
     }

}
```

Now, student would have both `goToWork` and `goToSchool` (sure, some students also work at a company, but let's not dive into multiple inheritance yet...). And I would neither move `goToSchool` into the `Person` class. Again, if I want to treat this `Student` as a `Student`, I need to declare it as a `Student`:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.goToSchool();
```

If I were to move all these methods to the `Person` class, `Person` would have two methods related to going to school and going to work, regardless of what type of `Person`. Not all `Person`s (people) go to school, and not all go to work.

Comment: So u r telling for every method in Parent there shld be method definition in child's anonymous inner class

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying, @JavaBeginner. Just if you want to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for All those Replied.I got the Concept Now.

In the Inline Class I am Using a Parent Reference.Its Like the one below.

```
Parent p = new Child()
```

So in order to access methods in child with Parent reference the child class should have redefined all the methods defined in Parent.

The same thing is happening in Anonymous Inner class where I am using a Parent reference. So whenever I add a new method in the Inline Class I should define the same method in the Parent class.Otherwise its going to generate a Error.

Comment: You're getting closer, but not quite there yet. If you have to "redefine methods in the parent" as you put it, to use the methods you want, then `p` is not a `Parent`, but a `Child`, and should be declared as `Child c = new Child()` instead. `Parent` is the superclass of `Child`, and should only have the methods that are related to beeing a `Parent`, as other classes also can extend `Child`.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes, when created from a class, extend that class. The original purpose of anonymous classes was to provide overriding implementation of the class/interface used to create it.

In your case, the `Parent` class is the superclass of the anonymous class. As a superclass reference, `Parent` can hold the singular anonymous subclass object but you can only access methods defined in the `Parent` class through the reference.

Imagine it as simply extending the `Parent` class, not redefining the `Parent` class.

Anonymous classes cannot be instantiated as their own separate entities. They exist as extensions/implementations of a class/interface.

```
objParent.displayMsg();
```

Here, `objParent` is a reference of class Parent, not the reference of the anonymous class.

Although anonymous class can have its own method declarations, they cannot be accessed through a reference because we cannot create a pure reference of the anonymous class. We'll always need the superclass/interface reference to hold the anonymous class object.